# RESTful WCF service security

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-binding, wcf-security, restful-authentication

How we could authenticate/authorize WCF RESTful service (that uses webHttpBinding (and not wsHttpBinding, like in SOAP case))?
I.e. we want to use Membership/Roles to permit (or prohibit) user consume each web method according his role.

Thanks in advance.
Ilan.

Comment: @simchona SOAP - Simple Object Access Protocol

Comment: Can you post some of your configuration file to know how you have your REST Service implemented? Is it via Restful API or using endpoints defined with webHttpBinding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use certificates to secure the service or send the username and password in the header. You can then add a behavior by implementing `IAuthorizationPolicy` to the service so that you don't have to implement the security check in every web service method that you expose.

```
public class CertificateAuthorizationPolicy : IAuthorizationPolicy
{

    public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
    {
        IIdentity identity;
        object untypedIdentities;
        if (!evaluationContext.Properties.TryGetValue("Identities", out untypedIdentities))
        {
            identity = null;
            return false;                                                                                                             
        }

        var identities = (IEnumerable<IIdentity>)untypedIdentities;

        identity = identities.Where(item => item.AuthenticationType == "X509").FirstOrDefault();

        var claimSet = (X509CertificateClaimSet)evaluationContext.ClaimSets[0];
        var certificate = claimSet.X509Certificate;

    }
```

In web.config you tell the service to use the authorization policy

```
    <behavior name="CertificateSecurityServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="CertificateAuthorizationPolicy, MyAssembly.Security" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
```

Another option is to setup SSL on the IIS Server so that it requires SSL and client certificate to connect to any page.

Comment: Very interesting.. We already bought and installed the VeriSign certificate - to use https instead of http. To IOperationBehavior, could I use it with webHttpBinding? Could you point me to some code snippet? Thanks.

Comment: I added a link with an implementation example

Comment: Great article, thanks. But we still don't know how to use IOperationBehavior, that you proposed, to permit/prohibit access to web methods using Microsoft Membership/Roles provider.

Comment: I've updated with the implementation. My memory failed me a bit, the security check is setup by using the IAuthorizationPolicy interface